# .NET CF application on Windows Mobile freezing with no details in the global exception handler

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I am developing a .net cf application for a windows mobile device - the Motorola ES400.

The application maintains a log file which logs all handled exceptions and the unhandled global exception which was registered in global scope of the application in the Main method.

For some reason, while I was running the application on the phone, the application just froze - which means that I was not able to click on any buttons on the application or perform any other actions with the stylus. The application was totally unresponsive. When I went back to the phone Windows Mobile OS Start menu->Task Manager and tried to close the application, I could not. The task manager would not close the application. When I checked the logs, I could not see any unhandled exception logged through the registeres unhandled global exception routine.

I don't understand what might be the problem here.

Does anyone have any idea on what might have happened based on your experience with .NET CF? Anywhere I could start looking or analyzing?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Subbu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get a hard fault (OS-level error like memeory access violation) then I've seen the system freeze while the Dr Watson logs are getting created.

On the ES400 I don't recall if there is a control panel applet to confugure the error reporting feature or not, but check there.

If it was creating such a log, bu default I think it goes in a subfolder under \windows.  But the whole process if configurable via the registry so you might want to look there.

See here for the topic in general:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee481217(v=winembedded.60).aspx

And here specifically for the registry settings:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee480226(v=winembedded.60).aspx

Answer (score 2):

There can be many reasons. In my experience, I suppose there is some infinite looping or call to some locked resource is happening. In such scenarios, try using CLR Profiler for .NET CF. CLR Profiler can show you what is going wrong and where. 
You can get it from here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13442
And about how to use it, there is series of blog posts, visit: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stevenpr/archive/2008/05/08/the-clr-profiler-for-the-net-compact-framework-series-index.aspx

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems similar to this a while ago. I was was using a barcode scanner driver that created a separate thread and looped until a barcode was scanned. When I tried to exit the application it would wait for the thread to stop, causing the application to freeze until a barcode was scanned. Task manager could not end the application either.

I believe if you have a foreground thread (Thread.IsBackground = false) this will prevent the process from terminating until it has ended - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx

Therefore your problem may be from a secondary thread that you have started up. If you are waiting for a thread, through a lock or something like that, and that thread is in an infinite loop, then this could be the cause of your problem. My most common cause for an accedental infinite loop is having a property getter referencing the property instead of the backing variable.

I hope this is of some help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have already implemented this for every thread used in the application because this approach is guaranteed to close the thread when the main thread closes.

Comment: @Subbu: You should give everyone who took the time to give you an answer a (+1) ...unless they told you to do something wrong!

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to catch and log this error, then put a `try...catch` around your code in the **main** function of your program.

In C#, this would be simply editing `Program.cs` from something like this:

```
static void Main() {
  Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

To something like this:

```
private static Form1 m_form;

static void Main() {
  try {
    m_form = new Form1();
    Application.Run(m_form);
  } catch (Exception err) {
    // log error
    if ((m_form != null) && !m_form.IsDisposed) {
      // you might want to save data on your form before it goes Bye-Bye.
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the method we use. Writing logs or events to the database often proves to be too problematic. At least if the exception is caught at source and displayed, the user has a message they can tell support.